# unexpected freeze while handling input

Tags: c

I've been trying to handle multiple functions which the user can select from, but for some reason, unexpected input isn't causing the developed reaction, freezing instead.

```
int main(){
    int done = 0, isModeValid = 1;
    char nextMode[15], *options[] = {"quit",  "test", "getASCII"};

    while(done == 0){
        cls();
        isModeValid = 0;
        text(1);
        currentOptions(options);
        gets(nextMode);
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < (sizeof(options)); i++){
            if(strcmp(nextMode, options[i]) == 0){
                 done = runMode(i);
                 break;
            }
            //Error seems to happen after this point
            if(strcmp(nextMode, options[i]) != 0 && i == sizeof(options)){
                cls();
                text(3);
                Sleep(750);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void cls(){
    system("cls");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking undefined behaviour. `sizeof` yields the size of the argument in *bytes*/`char`s, not the *length* of the array. So you are iterating over more elements than the array actually contains and try to access elements past its bounds.

Use `sizeof(options) / sizeof(options[0])` to get the length independent from the type of each entry.

Note: Declaring the array `static` would make its allocation and initialization before `main` is called. Your current version will do that each time the function is called. While uncritical for `main`, it will be significant for other functions which are called more than once.

Comment: upvoted. There should be no need to calculate it either. If it's statically allocated you know what its size is (# of elements). Otherwise, if it's allocated dynamically.... you know it just as well! :)

Comment: @Pynchia: If the size is known at compile-time, there is nothing lost as compared to using a constant. But for the question, the size is determined by the initializer, so no, we do not know the size actually, but would have to count anyway. (Not to forget about VLAs).

Comment: Yes of course. I was just kidding, implying whoever has allocated the memory knows and there should be a way to let your code know as well

Comment: @Pynchia: I actually prefer a struct with flexible array member if I have to allocate a dynamic array with varying size. Little sense in holding the length/size in a seperate variable.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number strings in `options`, you need `(sizeof(options)/sizeof(options[0]))`, not just `sizeof(options)`... so your `for` loop is looping too many times, and you're accessing out of bounds.

Also, your second `if` never executes because `i` will never get to `sizeof(options)`.